# How to send request for facebook authentication to the user from google app engine (python)?

Tags: google-app-engine, python-2.7, webapp2

I am a newbie to the googple-app-engine so please bear with my stupid question if you find it that way. I wanted request handler for user's facebook account(authentication code) to access its friend's list through python2.7 with webapp2 framework and app engine . Thank you in advance. Please write the code.

Answer (score 0):

You are probably going to want to use the python Facebook SDK if you are asking people to "write the code" for you. The code has already been written.

https://github.com/pythonforfacebook/facebook-sdk

> This client library is designed to support the Facebook Graph API and
>   the official Facebook JavaScript SDK, which is the canonical way to
>   implement Facebook authentication.

```
import facebook
graph = facebook.GraphAPI(oauth_access_token)
profile = graph.get_object("me")
friends = graph.get_connections("me", "friends")
graph.put_object("me", "feed", message="I am writing on my wall!")
```

See the docs for specifics about friends list etc. Using this you should be able to add in the relevant code to your existing handlers, assuming you don't also want SO to write those for you as well...